# Compatibility jhipster microservices 4.6.0 & 5.2.1 & 6.x.x

Tags: java, jhipster

we have microservices with 4.9.0 and with 5.2.1 and now we want create new microservices with 6.x.x is recommended have microservices with differents versions in the same registry?
We dont upgrade because we tried and is impossible we have a lot of code yet in old microservices.
And in gateway is imposible migrate angular 4 to angular 6 with our quantity of code.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used a recent registry with gateways and services generated by JHipster 3.9.0. Eureka REST API is quite stable. I have upgraded manually some services from Spring Boot 1.3 to 1.5 in order to be able to use hazelcast-eureka-one that required a more recent version of Spring Cloud.

I don't understand why you say it's impossible, unless you want to use `jhipster upgrade` or you don't have a good test coverage.

I don't plan to use `jhipster upgrade` at all, it would be a waste of time because of too many major versions until current. I prefer to copy my `.yo-rc.json` and JDL to a blank folder and generate with latest version of JHipster and then pick up what I need, step by step.

Upgrading from Angular 4 to 6 is easy, it should not be a problem for your team.

Overall, I don't see it as a JHipster problem, it's the same as if we had started from scratch without a generator.